# Serialization error on bitcoin transaction

Tags: javascript, transactions, bitcoin

**I am getting serialization error when i send bitcoin one adress to another** : *versions of npm  "bitcore-explorers": "^1.0.1",
"bitcore-lib": "^8.22.2"*

```
const explorers=require('bitcore-explorers')
var insight=new explorers.Insight();
var bitcore = require('bitcore-explorers/node_modules/bitcore-lib');
var privateKeyWIF='L4xkFv5sbttQcsgnTjzqJuQdNfHC5gk9zsK5HmaV822qu79zJA7L';
var privateKey = bitcore.PrivateKey.fromWIF(privateKeyWIF);
var sourceAddress = privateKey.toAddress();
var targetAddress = '1HgaQXpi9GC57zCPd1X8NHkPJaizEh6g8N'
insight.getUnspentUtxos(sourceAddress, function (error, utxos) {
  if (error) {
    console.log(error);
  } else {
    console.log(utxos);
    var tx = new bitcore.Transaction();
    tx.from(utxos);
    tx.to(targetAddress, 10000);
    tx.change(sourceAddress);
    tx.fee(50000)
    tx.sign(privateKey);
    console.log(tx.serialize());
    insight.broadcast(tx, function (error, transactionId) {
      if (error) {
        console.log("hii3")
        console.log(error);
      } else {
        console.log("hiii4")
        console.log(transactionId);
      }
    });
  }
});
///////
```

Source address: 1Mc4kW9KbVfcEWzYhXU46xxMHMFcDxUDsn
Target address: 1HgaQXpi9GC57zCPd1X8NHkPJaizEh6g8N
[ ]

```
throw serializationError;
^
```

undefined
Error

Answer (score 0):

`bitcore` is using `bitpay` as the default provider server, and for some reason, it is not working. They also recommend changing the default server in the [docs][1].
Try changing the provider to `zelcore` like this:

```
const explorers = require("bitcore-explorers");
const insight = new explorers.Insight("https://explorer.btc.zelcore.io");
```